# função preg_match_all

Tags: php

Tenho essa função:

```
preg_match_all('/(tvg-logo="(?<logo>.*?)".+group-title="(?<name>.*?)".+\n(?P<link>http?:\/\/.+))/', $response, $channels, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Ela faz uma varredura numa lista m3u8:

```
EXTINF:-1  tvg-logo="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/rHPGCpqsbg3WK90uig0KbxBtFrh.jpg" group-title="Vod! Ondemand!",Jumanji: Bem-Vindo à Selva (2017) - Dublado - 720p
http://cdn1.ntcdn.us/content/httpdelivery/filmes2018/JUMANJI2018DUB-ALTO.mp4
```

E exibe as informação com esse código:

```
foreach($channels as $channel): ?>
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="<?php echo $channel["link"] ?>" title="<?php echo $channel["name"] ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $channel["logo"] ?>" class="img-responsive img-circle" />
        <div id="info_bar">
          <?php echo $channel["name"] ?>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Só que preciso pegar as informações do nome, que está depois da virgula de group title.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Se possível tenta dessa forma: https://regex101.com/r/NZVf7X/1

Comment: É possível pegar partes diferentes? por exemplo: separar Nome do filme, ano, dublado ou legendado...

Comment: Sim, é possível. Porém é necessário que *todos* estejam no mesmo padrão. `Tìtulo (ano) - (Tipo do Audio) - (Qualidade)`. Caso contrário a expressão ficará enorme e poderá não funcionar como esperado.

Comment: Sim, todos seguem o mesmo padrão: group-title="Vod! Ondemand!",O Culto de Chucky (Dublado) - 2017 - 1080p. Só o que muda as vezes é o que está dentro de group-title.

Comment: Consegui separar o group-title do restante, mas não consegui separar só as parte... https://regex101.com/r/NZVf7X/2

Comment: Tenta dessa forma: https://regex101.com/r/NZVf7X/4

Comment: Opa, deu certo! Obrigadão!